# Jenkins - Stop deployment into next enviroment until signed off

Tags: jenkins

We have got a running Jenkins server that is used to deploy to our different environments DEV, TEST, UAT and PROD and we use Build with parameters, to select the environment variable as well as input the release ID.

what I'm looking to do is stop a Build from being able to be run in our Prod environment until QA have signed it off in UAT.

Does Jenkins have and support for this, ever natively or as a plug in ?

Comment: Not natively, but we support this via plugin connected to an external system which does approvals: plugin - https://plugins.jenkins.io/reliza-integration/ + approval feature video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzdZjMby6Is

Other alternatives include various pull request (or merge request) workflows.